# Make j and k act character-wise when used with operators

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, operator

When I use `j` or `k` with operators, they make the operator act line-wise - acting over two whole lines, as if I had used `Vj`/`Vk`. I want them to act character-wise so that they act until the current column in the line above/below, as they do with `vj`/`vk`, or when used as motions on their own.

Comment: `:help forced-motion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Matt says, use `{operator}vj` as per `:help forced-motion`. You can force line-wise, character-wise, and block-wise (think of it like "casting" the motion).